# Escaping double-backslash in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy script that should read a value from a registry key, on a remote machine. When I run reg query command on the local machine, or from another machine on the network, I get back the correct value. I also get the correct value when I run the Groovy script against the local machine (removing "\\' + hostname + '\").

When I run the code listed below, I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Application\": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

This leads me to believe that I am failing to escape the path correctly. If that's right, how should I escape a double-backslash?

Here is the script:

```
def hostname = '10.1.1.2'
def outVal = ''

try {
    output = 'reg query \\\\' + hostname + '\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\SynAEM\\UDF1 -v PatchGroup'.execute().text
    outVal = output.tokenize(' ')[-1]
}
catch(Exception e) {
    outVal = 'NotSpecified'
    println e

}
println 'PatchGroup=' + outVal

return 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with backslashes. It's to do with precedence. What you wrote is equivalent to:

```
output = 'reg query \\\\' + hostname +
     ('\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\SynAEM\\UDF1 -v PatchGroup'.execute().text)
```

The `execute()` method was trying to run the last string, ie the registry name. What you need is:

```
output = ('reg query \\\\' + hostname + '\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\SynAEM\\UDF1 -v PatchGroup').execute().text
```

or, possibly a bit clearer:

```
output = "reg query \\\\$hostname\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\SynAEM\\UDF1 -v PatchGroup".execute().text
```